# Create global variable in XSL from specific tag in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having trouble creating a global variable in my XSL 1.0 stylesheet.  I want to create the variable from the value of an XML tag that is in the XML I'm trying to transform.  Here is what my XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<config name="test report" xmlns="http://www.example.com/CONFIG">

    <the_one_i_want>1000</the_one_i_want>

    <!-- lots of other stuff -->

</config>
```

And here is what my XSL looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:CONFIG="http://www.example.com/CONFIG">

    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="normal_global_variable">100</xsl:variable><!-- This works fine -->
    <xsl:variable name="variable_from_xml"><xsl:value-of select="/config/the_one_i_want/value"/></xsl:variable><!-- This does not work -->

    <!-- lots of other stuff -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So I would expect that `variable_from_xml` would have a value of `1000`, but it does not.  What am I doing wrong?

**P.S.** The XML tag named `the_one_i_want` is unique and only appears once in my XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is one of namespaces. The `<the_one_i_want>` element that you're after is bound to the `http://www.example.com/CONFIG` namespace (which you've already defined in your XSLT).

**Therefore, simply change this:**

```
<xsl:variable name="variable_from_xml">
  <xsl:value-of select="/config/the_one_i_want/value"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

**to this:**

```
<xsl:variable name="variable_from_xml" select="/CONFIG:config/CONFIG:the_one_i_want"/>
```

**or, even more simply:**

```
<xsl:variable name="variable_from_xml" select="/*/CONFIG:the_one_i_want"/>
```

Comment: Didn't try the first solution, but the second solution worked great.  Thanks!